# Using PHPMailer to mail phpexcel doc

Tags: php, phpmailer, phpexcel

I'm trying to use phpmailer on a script that relies on phpexcel to generate a spreadsheet.

It saves the spreadsheet perfectly and I get no phpmailer errors, but it's not sending. I'm not sure what would be the issue if it's not sending *or* showing errors.

Here's the portion that saves the excel and generates the mailer:

```
                $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel2007");
                $writer->save('Coaching Report - Test.xlsx');

                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
                 //$address = "s";
                $address = "omitted";

                $date = date("D M d, Y");


                try{
                $mail->setFrom("omitted");
                $mail->addAddress($address);
                $mail->AddAttachment($writer,"Coaching Report $date.xlsx");
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject    = "Weekly Coaching Report";
                $mail->Body       = "Attached is the weekly coaching report for " . $date;
                $mail->Send();
                echo 'message sent';

                } catch (Exception $e){
                    echo 'message failed';
                    echo 'mail error:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                }

                mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saved excel file with this name: Coaching Report - Test.xlsx

But when want to attach this file call it with this name: Coaching Report $date.xlsx

That's incorrect. You must call the file in attachment with an existed filename.

Comment: Ah, when I use it on a CSV file I do that to append today's date to it and I assumed that would work here as well. I'll give it a shot now